# Ubuntu keeps randomly switching disks

Tags: disk, fstab, disk-utility

It took me a while to notice, but here's what happens. I have 2 disks on my computer.

On startup, Ubuntu's Disk Utility tells me one is `sda` and the other `sdb`. On restart it switches them and on another restart, switches again. It's impossible for me to set my `/etc/fstab` with the OS randomly switching my disks. I am not changing any settings in BIOS.

How can I make this stop?

Answer (score 3):

Use the device mapper. Instead of mounting, say, /dev/sda1, mount by ID. This is how the respective line from fstab would look like:

```
UUID=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx  / ext3 relatime,error=remount-ro  0  1
```

You can find out what the id's are with `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda3: UUID="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ext3"
```

The above UUID is what you should use in the fstab entry above.

From the `fstab` man page:

> Instead of giving the device explicitly, one may indicate the (ext2 or xfs) filesystem that is to be mounted by its  UUID  or  volume  label  (cf.
>          e2label(8)  or  xfs_admin(8)), writing LABEL= or UUID=, e.g., 'LABEL=Boot' or 'UUID=3e6be9de-8139-11d1-9106-a43f08d823a6'.  This will
>          make the system more robust: adding or removing a SCSI disk changes the disk device name but not the filesystem volume label.

Comment: Ubuntu is using UUID for a long while now. I assume he already has this enabled by default

Comment: @Anwar I assumed he meant a secondary drive added after the installation.

Comment: @Flavian if it solved the question, please mark the answer as accepted answer by clicking on the gray icon at the top left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is why Grub uses UUID-s instead of old-fashion `/dev/sd*` reference. The UUID is unique, and it doesn't matter in which order is seeing the OS the disks. So, update your `/etc/fstab` to use UUID-s, and you sould not worry about it anymore. (More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID).)

The reason for switching should be a BIOS error (this needs some more investigation).